# Reduce Whitespace in pcolor matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, color-mapping, prettyplotlib

I'm currently working on plotting pivoted tables using matplotlib pcolor but my axes are not functioning like i would like them to.
I plot the tables using:

```
pyl.pcolor(pivot_99)
pyl.colorbar()
pyp.suptitle('Pivot 99', fontsize=14)
pyp.xlabel('Site Number', fontsize=12)
pyp.ylabel('Site Number', fontsize=12)
pyp.yticks(arange(len(pivot_99.index)),pivot_99.index)
pyp.xticks(arange(len(pivot_99.columns)),pivot_99.columns, rotation = 90)
pyl.savefig('Pivot 99.png')
pyl.show()
```

Where pivot_99 is a dataframe consisting of numbers between 0 and 1. The length of the index and columns are always the same but are different values for different years. When I plot pivot_99 it looks fine:
[image: Pivot 1999]

However when I plot the 2000 Heatmap there is extra space on the top and right.

[image: Pivot 2000]

Does anyone know why this is happening or how I can fix the graph so only space with color is showing? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `set_xlim` and `set_ylim` like in this example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyp

pyp.gca().set_xlim((1,10))
pyp.gca().set_ylim((1,12))
pyp.plot([1,2],[1,2])
pyp.show()
```

You can try with `xlim=ylim=558`, I can test it because I don't have your data :(

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use [prettyplotlib](https://github.com/olgabot/prettyplotlib) which will set your `xlim`, `ylim` for you automatically, remove your spines and ticks, and give you a reasonable colorbar.

```
import prettyplotlib as ppl
ppl.pcolormesh(pivot_99)
```

Full disclosure: I am the prettyplotlib author :)